# How to populate multiple JSONArrays

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am getting response from JSON i which I am getting more than two jSONArrays. like this i have take snapshot of logcat data [here is logcat data which I am fetching jsonarrays from my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqNb5.png)

now question is how i can populate all of these arraylist in single arraylist and  how to show in recyclerView. here is my response code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray hotDealProduct =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("ListProduct");
                        setHotDealAdapter(hotDealProduct);
                        Log.e(TAG,hotDealProduct.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

here is my setHotDealAdapter()code:

```
for (int i=0;i<hotDealProduct.length();i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = hotDealProduct.getJSONObject(i);
            final String discount = object.getString("discount");
            final String price = object.getString("Price");
            final String salePrice = object.getString("SalePrice");
            final String image = object.getString("MainImage");
            final String name = object.getString("Name");
            products.add(new HotDeal(1,discount, price ,image,salePrice,name));
            adapter = new HotDealAdapter(context,products);
            rvHotDeal.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,2));
            rvHotDeal.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what is the issue I see you already did it

Comment: problem is how i can append all jsonarrayList to a single arraylist

Comment: I'll post an answer better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `setHotDealAdapter()` like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<hotDealProduct.length();i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = hotDealProduct.getJSONObject(i);
                final String discount = object.getString("discount");
                final String price = object.getString("Price");
                final String salePrice = object.getString("SalePrice");
                final String image = object.getString("MainImage");
                final String name = object.getString("Name");
                products.add(new HotDeal(1,discount, price ,image,salePrice,name));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                adapter = new HotDealAdapter(context,products);
                rvHotDeal.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,2));
                rvHotDeal.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: that is working correctly but not fetching the data of second array. it shows exception that path must not be empty

Answer (score 0):

I see you did it correctly but you need to init and set the adapter out side the for loop and in every time you create new adapter and asign new one to the recycler.

try this code please

```
for (int i=0;i<hotDealProduct.length();i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = hotDealProduct.getJSONObject(i);
                    final String discount = object.getString("discount");
                    final String price = object.getString("Price");
                    final String salePrice = object.getString("SalePrice");
                    final String image = object.getString("MainImage");
                    final String name = object.getString("Name");
                    products.add(new HotDeal(1,discount, price ,image,salePrice,name));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}

    adapter = new HotDealAdapter(context,products);
                    rvHotDeal.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,2));
                    rvHotDeal.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: that is working correctly but not fetching the data of second array. it shows exception that path must not be empty. it is showing the data of 1st array not for other arrays. how can show the data of second array

Comment: isn't they in same array named `hotDealProduct`?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you simply must setup adapter out of loop,

I mean following codes:

```html
adapter = new HotDealAdapter(context,products);
            rvHotDeal.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,2));
            rvHotDeal.setAdapter(adapter);
```

you have to call it at once. Since you change adapter completely, you don't need  following line:

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

If you want to add item's one by one, first set adapter then get adapter and add Item to it, then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); (this solution is time consuming and not preferred) .

Correct Code:

```html
try {
  for (int i=0;i<hotDealProduct.length();i++) {               
      JSONObject object = hotDealProduct.getJSONObject(i);
      String discount = object.getString("discount");
      String price = object.getString("Price");
      String salePrice = object.getString("SalePrice");
      String image = object.getString("MainImage");
      String name = object.getString("Name");
      products.add(new HotDeal(1,discount, price ,image,salePrice,name));
    }

    adapter = new HotDealAdapter(context,products);
    rvHotDeal.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,2));
    rvHotDeal.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Best practices** and for **Robust** performance ->

**A.** Create **POJO** or **Model** of your json response.

For this step ->

1) Copy your json response and paste [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

2) There select **Source Type : JSON** and **Annotation Style : Gson**.

3) Click on generate or preview as per your choice and create your model class.

**B.** Import **GSON** dependency in your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

**C.** In your activity or fragment class ->

Implement code as below :

```
ArrayList<YourPOJO> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();

{
// Your code implementation of binding data to recyclerview : 

GsonBuilder gsonbuilder= new GsonBuilder();

Gson gson=gsonbuilder.create();
//response = its your json string from server
itemList =gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<YourPOJO>>(){}.getType());

yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(itemList);

yourRecyclerview.setAdapter(yourAdapter);

}
```

By this method you don't have to manually write code to parse your json and bind it to your view.

Now in case if you want some object of your json to be parsed ( In your case you want to parse only JSONArray ) in above code replace `response` with `yourJsonArray.toString()`

Hope that it solve your problem.